# didBegin method in swift not being called for all collisions

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where a ball can pass through poles of the same color but collides with and ends the game if the pole is a different color. Initially, my method of collision detection worked when there were two poles but I have now added a third and it does not work. The addition of the extra pole should have no bearing on the collisions. However, now the game won't detect collision of the third pole, will always collide with the second regardless of color, and the first pole works as expected. Pole is a class and all three poles are objects of that class. The didBegin method. is not even called for the third pole and I am not sure why

```
 ball?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    ball?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
    ball?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2
```

in Pole class :

```
   self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
```

Comment: Clearly you are going to have to provide more context than what you have here.  I honestly would like you to try and solve your problem using only what you have provided.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Im sorry i am still a relatively new swift developer and I would like to provide as much information as needed. What code blocks should I include? I was not sure of what to show because I have not been able to narrow down the issue past the fact that the physics simulations are not working correctly.

Comment: I can't tell you what you need to include, it is your code not mine.  However, you need to provide the code that causes the actual problem here.  You need to start learning how to be able to read your code and explain what it does.  Once you start understanding what your code does,  you will be able to provide the chunks that is not performing in the way you think it is suppose to perform.